# How to import Tab delimited Text files into Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple text files (.txt) with Tab delimited in a folder. The text file contains first line as column headings. I have one pre defined excel template with column names. I am able to import the text files into excel template. But, what i need to do is how to delimit if the column heading not match with Excel column headings Through VBA. 
Thanks in advance for any help .....

Comment: How do you want to detect any discrepancies between the template heading and the imported heading? Do you want to compare them side by side? compare the first row of the template with the first row of any imported file? And what do you want to do when you detect a discrepancy?

Comment: Hi Robert thank you for your quick response, I need to compare as you said. If the column heading are did not match, the file not required to import. the file will be skipped and another file will be taken place

Comment: Do you already have any VBA code in use? How do you "open" those multiple files? And why should some data headers match and others not?

Comment: Oh, by the way, do you need to "read" the dataheaders from the template, or can you define them inside VBA. This way you only need to compare cell.values against variables inside VBA, unless there are hundreds of headers....

Comment: You need to explain how you decide File 1 is correct but File 2 is not.  For example, suppose you want to add the data to the bottom of a particular sheet.  The column headings of that sheet could define what the column headings of the file should be.  If you expect FieldA, FieldB, FieldC but you get FieldB, FieldC, FieldA would you reject the file or would you rearrange the columns as you imported the data?

Comment: Can you share the code section you have right now that deals with loading the different files and comparing the data headers? Or do you have to start from scratch. If so that you need to explain the rules with regard to which file to open. I.e. is it File001.txt then File002.txt or all .txt files in a certain directory? Once you have the master file and a delimited txt file open, comparing the data headers is relatively easy using worksheet("wb1").cells(1,Nr).value = worksheet("wb2").cells(1,Nr).value...

Comment: I dont know how to compare the fields. But i am only importing the text files through VBA and manually checking if the fields are correct or not. I need to import all the file .txt files from a folder which is selected. If possible please provide code. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible to do it in Excel itself, in Office 2010 its in the Data tab > Text to columns. There you can select that its delimited by tabs, and there you go, your data should be columnised

Comment: What i am asking is if the columns are not similar in excel, how to delimit the Text file.

Comment: Hi Robert thank you for your quick response, I need to compare as you said. If the column heading are did not match, the file not required to import. the file will be skipped and another file will be taken place